# Establishing ssh session using Back To My Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, icloud, ssh, back-to-my-mac

I am trying to establish a ssh session to my MacBook using "Back to my Mac". So I turned the "Back to my Mac" option **on** in iCloud and ticked the remote sign in box. But if I issue the command

```
ssh user_name@computer_name.number.members.btmm.icloud.com
```

the terminal just goes into the next line and stays black.
Sorry for not providing more information, but I don't know much about this, so I don't know what else information to provide.

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

**Edit**: As suggested I used the -vvvv flag and got:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "computer_name.number.members.btmm.icloud.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to computer_name.number.members.btmm.icloud.com [private_IPv6_address] port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: Connecting to computer_name.number.members.btmm.icloud.com [private_IPv6_address] port 22: Operation timed out
```

Also the command

```
ssh localhost
```

works without any troubles.

Comment: You can get more useful debug information out of `ssh` by calling it with `-vvvv` as an option. That'll at least tell you where it's stalled in the connection establishment process.

Comment: So your remote computer is unreachable, that's all `-vvvv` tells us. Let's debug in in a chat room. I have questions for you: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62332/debugging-btmm-ssh

Comment: We established that all BTMM settings, computer firewall and ssh settings are correct but BTMM is trying to ssh to an IPv6 address that appears to be un-routable. Not sure where to take it from here but maybe someone smarter than me can help figure it out.

Comment: Although not 100% the answer - I wanted to link to some great answers that have helped me greatly with mDNS and BTMM - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53719/can-i-use-back-to-my-macs-mdns-address-and-for-ssh-and-other-routing-of-traffic and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14049/is-it-possible-to-use-back-to-my-mac-dns-or-routing-information-from-the-command

Answer (score 9):

"Back to my Mac" uses a special tunnel device configured with two - more or less random and unique - IPv6 addresses from the local address room:

- a link local address: fe80...
- a unique local unicast (ULA): fc00… to fdff…

All IPv6 traffic (computer_name.number.members.btmm.icloud.com is the DNS name of a IPv6 host/device!) is [wrapped into IPv4 packets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6281), so that a IPv6 capable router isn't needed. On the Apple side it's unwrapped - probably with some 6in4 relay - and then routed to the remote device.

Apparently this doesn't work if you want to ssh from your own host into your own host (aka `ssh -6 %localhost-utun1-ULA%`). It works with a second device (also registered with your Apple ID in iCloud) in your own private or a remote network.

It's really slow though (tested with two Sierra VMs on one hosting Mac all using the same physical network interface!).

Comment: Also - hooray for [RFC 6281](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6281) and [this Q&A here on back to my Mac design and function](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283349/5472)